# PDO Updatequery changes id without asking?

Tags: sql, pdo

im having a little problem with an UPDATE query run via PDO.
This is the part where im having an issue with:

```
$query="UPDATE snippets SET snippet= ? WHERE id= ?";
$query=$pdo->prepare($query);
$query->execute([ $_POST['snippet'] , $_POST['id'] ]);
```

it works, as in it changes the snippet to what it is supposed to, but for some reason the id of the affected column also changes (counting up).
The id is set as AUTO_INCREMENT on the SQL-Server but as far as i know that should only aply to new columns, not updates.
If i run the exact same query using a thrid party tool it doesnt change the id, just the snippet value. I've tried it out with HeidiSQL and phpMyAdmin.

Any insight into why this happens is much appreciated

Comment: Any triggers on the table?

Comment: no. also wouldnt those triggers also fire if i did the query with a different tool? its only pdo that gives this result